# Adding #+LATEX: \newpage before a heading

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In latex export of orgmode, I would like to be able to add `#+LATEX: \newpage` before a heading with `newpage` tag, so I don't have to manually specify `#+LATEX: \newpage` when I want a heading to be on a new page.

It seems I can add a hook to `org-export-before-parsing-hook`, but I have not been able to do it. The following code successfully adds `#+LATEX: \newpage` before a heading with `newpage` tag, but when I try to add `\n` (`(insert-string "#+LATEX: \\newpage\n")`), exporting gets stuck with the message `org-babel-exp process txt at position 280541...`. I suspect inserting `\n` messes up the position.

```
(defun org/parse-headings (backend)
  (if (member backend '(latex))
      (org-map-entries
       (lambda ()
         (progn
           (insert-string "#+LATEX: \\newpage")
           ))
       "+newpage")
    )
)

(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'org/parse-headings)
```

Comment: See http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/93971

Comment: [Latex classes](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/article-class.html) are the place for such format tweaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need simple modification of [Rasmus solution](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/93971) given by [mankoff](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/91/mankoff).

```
(defun org/get-headline-string-element  (headline backend info)
  (let ((prop-point (next-property-change 0 headline)))
    (if prop-point (plist-get (text-properties-at prop-point headline) :parent))))

(defun org/ensure-latex-clearpage (headline backend info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (let ((elmnt (org/get-headline-string-element headline backend info)))
      (when (member "newpage" (org-element-property :tags elmnt))
        (concat "\\clearpage\n" headline)))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions
             'org/ensure-latex-clearpage)
```

I think that `\clearpage` suits here better than `\newpage` (check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/is-it-wrong-to-use-clearpage-instead-of-newpage) for more info).

All credits goes to [Rasmus](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/93971) and [mankoff](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/91/mankoff).

Comment: Note, `org/get-headline-string-element` relies on a hack and it will only work for headlines that are not all `~verbatim~` or `=code=`.  Also, wouldn't you want to put `"\\clearpage\n"` *before* `headline`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure if this is related to the org-version, but I'm getting `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-filter-headline-functions` when I try to run this.

Comment: I got it - I should have done `(eval-after-load 'ox '(add-to-list ...`.

Comment: It seems to be working well after I put `"\\clearpage\n"` before `headline`. (the answer is edited). Thank you. As @rasmus said, it does not work for headlines that are all with `~verbatim~` or `=code=, but I rarely use that so this script is currently my best option.